# Publishing Map as a Feature Service Ends up as a Map Server

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, mapserver, map-service, feature-service

Following ESRI documentation at [Here](http://csisalesesri01:6080/arcgis/manager/service.html?name=ElectricData.MapServer)

[image]

I am trying to publish a Map as Feature Server by enabling the Feature Access on Capability bur when I publish the Map the result looks like

[image]

As you can see the URL ends with /MapServer while I need to get a **/FeatureServer** like

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Only the MapServer REST URL gets displayed automatically. Although the REST URL only shows the MapServer address, if you replace MapServer with FeatureServer in the URL (as you've done in the image above), then copy this into your web browser, you should get to the Feature Server REST site.